# ios 7 - choosing photo from gallery resets statusBarStyle

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview, ios7-statusbar

I have an `iOS` 7 app and I have set the status bar text to white in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as follows:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

I have a webview with a javascript that calls the native `Image Picker`. In the `Image Picker`, when I choose a Photo from the Gallery, the status bar text is reset to black.

One way to correct this is to apply the above code again when the `Image Picker` closes. However, I cannot detect this event since it is on the webview.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Got solutions for this/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by implementing this:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}
```

As soon as the Photo Gallery closes, this code is called.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code in ViewController it works for me

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
  }
```

Comment: My `UIViewController` is a single page with no navigation bar and so on, so this method does not get call.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below step.

```
-> Set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO" in the plist
```

And then use

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

        [UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

}
```

Comment: I have already ` Set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" to "NO" in the plist`

Answer (score 0):

there is no instance method to change the color of status bar text. so you have to customize the status bar. you can check this link once..
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/